# Настройка i2p в linux

Tags: linux, сеть

Когда то давно ставил i2p на Виндовс. Выскочила табличка, сколько вы хотите выделить дискового пространства для i2p и как только я нажал ОК мой сетевой трафик подскочил и начал качать что то, потом я все выключил и удалил. Теперь спустя какое то время решил опять вернуться к этой теме и попробовать уже на linux. Все скачал все запустил но вот той заветной таблички так и не появилось, соответственно как я понял i2p у меня не работает. Пробовал запустить как системный демон, тоже самое висело минут 20 и сеть так и не подскачила. Нашел только как выделить ОЗУ под i2p. Но как сделать что бы сама сеть работала под Linux?

Comment: непонятно, что именно вы там устанавливали что в первом, что во втором случае, но вообще-то проект [i2p](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/I2P) не имеет никакого отношения к «выделению дискового пространства».

Comment: в faq это чётко оговорено: [**Storage**:
I2P does not do distributed storage of content, this has to be specifically installed and configured by the user (with Tahoe-LAFS, for example). That is a feature of a different anonymous network, Freenet. By running I2P, you are not storing content for anyone.](https://geti2p.net/ru/faq#badcontent)